# Laravel Auth::check() AND/OR Request::user() return null/false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I'm a newbie in Laravel and currently trying to use LTS.

Actually I'm working on a project where I used `maatwebsite/laravel-sidebar` with `trieu/trusty`. So, for using the `authorize()` function of sidebar via implementing `SidebarExtender`, I'm unable to get/match the current logged-in user/current logged-in user permissions.

I also tried this with a middleware with `Guard contract` and after that the `Auth facade`, but no luck.

At last I make a Contract interface called `AuthenticationInterface` and a repository called `AuthenticationRepo` with `hasAccess()` [returns `Request::user()` OR `Auth::user()`] and register/bind them into the service provider. But here also, the Auth/Request method doesn't work. I always get 'null/false' even after the user is logged-in.

So, please can anybody gives me the solution...

UPDATE : Code

1. UserInterface [Contracts]:

> Blockquote

```
 interface UserInterface
 {
   public function hasAccess($permissions);
 }
```

2. UserRepo [Repositories]:

> Blockquote

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
 use Modules\User\Models\User;

 class UserRepo implements UserInterface
 {
   public function hasAccess($permissions)
   {
      if ($user = Request::user()) { // use Auth; -> Auth::user()
        return $user->can($permissions);
      }

      return false;
   }
 }
```

3. SidebarExtender:

> Blockquote

```
  use Maatwebsite\Sidebar\Menu;
  use Maatwebsite\Sidebar\Item;
  use Maatwebsite\Sidebar\Group;
  use Maatwebsite\Sidebar\SidebarExtender;
  use App\Sidebar\BaseSidebar;

  class UserSidebarExtender extends BaseSidebar implements SidebarExtender
  {
    public function extendWith(Menu $menu)
    {
       dd($this->auth->check());
       $menu->group('UserSidebar', function(Group $group){
           $group->weight(100);
           $group->item('Try', function (Item $item) {
             $item->icon('fa fa-cogs');
             $item->weight(100);
             $item->route('dashboard');
             $item->authorize(
                 $this->auth->hasAccess('manage.blog')
             );
           });
         });
         return $menu;
     }
  }
```

4. BaseSidebar:

> Blockquote

```
 use Modules\User\Repositories\UserInterface as Auth;
 //use Closure;
 //use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
 abstract class BaseSidebar
 {
    protected $auth;
   public function __construct(Guard $auth)
   {
      $this->auth = $auth;
   }
 }
```

I'm also using 2 files aka `modulesidebar` and `createsidebar`, where `createsideabr` is used in `view()->creator(...)` and `modulesidebar` is registered via `Maatwebsite\Sidebar\SidebarManager` for automatic modification with sidebar :) Everything works great except the `hasAccess` function...

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Plz post your actual code.

Comment: i have used https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust for authentication / roles etc. its a pretty easy to use and fast to setup i would highly recommend it.

Comment: @SariYono: I agree with you, but I'm using Laravel 5.2 and maybe `entrust` still not support this.

Comment: I have it setup at 5.2 as well, what you would need to change is the caching driver to array and it should work just fine.

Comment: @SariYono: Can I use it (zizaco/entrust) in a middleware for checking the alloted permissions of authenticated users?

Comment: yes you could do something like  `Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@welcome');
    Route::get('/manage', ['middleware' => ['permission:manage-admins'], 'uses' => 'AdminController@manageAdmins']);
});
`  read the installs there is a step where you have to add it to the service providers / aliases @AnandPilania

Comment: @SariYono: Thanks. But at first, let me try to overcome this situation/question.

Comment: @SariYono: I checked `zizaco/entrust`'s `composer.json` file. Please take a look of the `require` section...

Comment: I guess im not sure what the issue with it is ? are you referring to the cache? you are still using cache just changing the driver to array so in your .env you would want to do something like `CACHE_DRIVER=array` unless you are using memcache which supports tags. database and file dont support cache.